# Why can't I get data directly from a sealed class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I hope to get data from a sealed class `Result<out R>`, but `val mydata = queryList.data` cause the following error, how can I fix it?

**Error Information**
*Smart cast to 'Result.Success<Flow<List>>' is impossible, because 'queryList' is a property that has open or custom getter*

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(
    name: String   
) {
     Column( ) {
        val queryList by produceState(initialValue = aa() ) {
            value = mViewMode.listRecord()
        }

        when (queryList) {
            is Result.Error -> {}
            is Result.Loading -> {}
            is Result.Success -> {
                val mydata = queryList.data //It cause error
            }
        }
    }
}


sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
    object Loading : Result<Nothing>()
}


fun aa(): Result<Flow<List<MRecord>>> {
    return Result.Loading
}
```

Comment: The `by produceState()` delegate means that `queryList` is not a simple `val` property that the compiler can evaluate and make guarantees about. There's know way for the compiler to know that repeated accesses of `queryList` will return the exact same value, and so it cannot smart-cast the result.

Comment: Thanks! How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cache the returned property value in a local variable so it can be smart cast. It can’t be smart cast without a local variable because it’s a delegated property.

You can do it right in the `when` statement:

```
when (val result = queryList) {
    is Result.Error -> {}
    is Result.Loading -> {}
    is Result.Success -> {
        val mydata = result.data
        // ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the error text, Kotlin cannot be sure that the next call to your delegated property `queryList` has the same type as the last one, and hence the variable cannot be smart cast. This can be solved by casting your variable explicitly:

```
when (queryList) {
    is Result.Error -> {}
    is Result.Loading -> {}
    is Result.Success -> {
        val mydata = (queryList as Result.Success).data
    }
}
```

If your property delegate does in fact create a new element each time you call `queryList`, it is advisable to store the value you are checking in a new variable like this:

```
val q = queryList
when (q) {
    is Result.Error -> {}
    is Result.Loading -> {}
    is Result.Success -> {
        val mydata = q.data
    }
}
```

Note that in this case Kotlin is able to smart cast `q.data` because `q` is just a simple read-only variable.